# Colocando em ordem alfabética um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, array

Eu tenho um array de objetos e quero colocar em ordem alfabética mas não estou conseguindo pelo javascript, vou colocar como o array está estruturado e o código para chamar na página

```
var json = [
  {
        "ID":"1",
        "TÍTULO":"Algum titulo",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Fulano",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":""
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Cicrano",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"instituição"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Nomes",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Nomes"
              }
        ]
  },
  {
        "ID":"2",
        "TÍTULO":"Algum titulo 2",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"algum nome",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Nomes"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Nomes",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Nomes"
              }
        ]
  }
];

var filter = json.filter(x => x.AUTORES.some(autor => autor.AUTOR));    
    for(var i=0;i<filter.length; i++){
        for(var j=0;j<filter[i].AUTORES.length; j++){
            var html = '<tr bgcolor="#F5F5F5">';
            html +='<td width="13%">' +filter[i].AUTORES[j].AUTOR+'</td>';
            html +='</tr>';
            $('table tbody').append(html);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Está bem vaga sua questão, ordenar em ordem alfabética por qual propriedade?

Comment: Na propriedade Autores

Answer (score 0):

O callback passado em sort recebe dois argumentos, que são os dois itens que você deve comparar, e então retornar um número maior que 0 para dizer que o primeiro elemento é maior, ou vice-versa.

No seu caso, para ordenar por título seria:

```
var ordenados = json.sort((livroA, livroB) => livroA['TÍTULO'] > livroB['TÍTULO'] ? 1 : -1);
```

Para organizar por autor você teria que organizar o nome dos autores também, não é um código eficiente, mas isso funciona:

```
var ordenados = json.sort((livroA, livroB) => 
    livroA.AUTORES.map(a => a.AUTOR).sort().join(' ') > 
    livroB.AUTORES.map(a => a.AUTOR).sort().join(' ') ? 1 : -1);
```

E se for necessário ignorar caixa alta:

```
var ordenados = json.sort((livroA, livroB) => 
    livroA.AUTORES.map(a => a.AUTOR.toLowerCase()).sort().join(' ') > 
    livroB.AUTORES.map(a => a.AUTOR.toLowerCase()).sort().join(' ') ? 1 : -1);
```

Comment: A conexão entre o `filter` e o `sort` está meio confusa na sua resposta

Comment: Acho que interpretei mal o código postado.

Comment: O do titulo consegui fazer, mas o dos autores não, tentei com esse método de cima mas não fica em ordem alfabética